# YOLOv7 fine tuning with unbalanced dataset

Tags: object-detection, pytorch, object-recognition, yolo

I have a question about training object detection models especially using the YOLOv7 algorithm.

I use a [Soccer Players Dataset](https://universe.roboflow.com/roboflow-100/soccer-players-5fuqs) from the Roboflow. The dataset is very unbalanced.

I trained the model using basic hyperparameters and it detects all objects on images but the predicted label is invalid. The model predicts everything as a player (but for example one person on an image is a referee).

How can I improve label prediction accuracy?

Comment: Maybe you should explain for how long you trained your model and what these basic hyper-parameters are.

Comment: I trained for 100 epochs, Basic hyperparameters are from the hyp.scratch.custom.yaml, but I wasn't changed values in this file.